# I have got Tencent TBS SDK error while publishing my flutter app on google playstore

Tags: flutter, google-play, flutter-dependencies

I got that error more than three time while I start publishing app on Google playstore :

`We found that your app is using Tencent TBS SDK which contains code to download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play.

If necessary, you can consult your SDK provider(s) for further information.

Affected Version(s):
App Bundle:88, App Bundle:88, App Bundle:88, App Bundle:86, App Bundle:86, App Bundle:86`

After some research I got that this is related to flutter_filereader package but I don't use it.
Here is the content of my pubspec.yaml.

'''

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.6.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.1.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^20.3.52
  # syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^20.3.52
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^20.3.52
  # table_calendar: ^3.0.4
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+5
  currency_picker: ^2.0.8
  country_currency_pickers: ^2.0.0
  select_form_field: "^2.2.0"
  # grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  # money_converter: ^2.0.1
  circular_countdown_timer: ^0.2.1
  progress_timeline: ^0.0.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.3
  dio: ^4.0.6
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  file_picker: ^4.6.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  http: ^0.13.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  numberpicker: ^2.0.1
  multi_image_picker2: ^5.0.2
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  flutter_tawk: ^0.1.0
  #emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.0.8
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  liquid_progress_indicator: ^0.4.0
  share_plus: ^4.0.10+1
  #open_file: ^3.2.1
  flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.10
  contacts_service: ^0.6.3
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  #ussd_advanced: ^1.0.0
  flutter_paypal: ^0.0.7
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_quill: 
  open_filex: ^3.4.0
```

'''

Someone can help me to solve that issue...? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check open file x plugin this not allowed by Google